# Clash of Clans - Connecting Account Failed, Why?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I tried connecting to my google account in an attempt to gain access to my loss account, [![and to my suprise it works
][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JxR9T.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JxR9T.jpg)

but when i was connecting to my supercell id  it did not work saying that i have no  account connected to supercell somehow then i began thinking then i realize what happen. i lost my account just after supercell id was introduced and i haven't connected into it, so i permanetly? lose my account.

now can anybody help me with this situation

Answer (score 2):

I think your best bet is [contacting support](https://forum.supercell.com/showthread.php/801163-Contact-Supercell-In-Out-of-game).

Provide as much info as you can, such as:

- Name of the lost village
- Name of the clan the lost village is a part of (to help track it
  down)
- Town Hall level of your lost village
- Last date & time played
- Player level in village (if available)

And they should be able to help you connect your village to your Google account.